# liferay osgi load optional class from another bundle

Tags: java, liferay, osgi, classloader

I have two (Liferay 7) osgi bundles, A and B such that

- A may or may not be deployed
- B is always deployed

I need to achieve:

Only if bundle A is deployed, class b in bundle B should create an object of class a in bundle A.

I do not want to put bundle A as a compile dependency in B's build.gradle, I would like to load directly in class b of bundle B if the above "Only if..." is true.

What I've tried (in bundle B):

```
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<SomeInterface> clazz =
            (Class<SomeInterface>) Class.forName(
                BUNDLE_A_CLASS_NAME);

        if (null != clazz &&
            Bundle.ACTIVE == FrameworkUtil.getBundle(clazz).getState()) {
            SomeInterface x = clazz.newInstance();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // handle this
    }
```

...

Where SomeInterface x is an interface I have on the classpath but clazz.newInstance() is an implementation in bundle A.

--

I have also tried adding to B's bnd.bnd file

1- `DynamicImport-Package: *` to the bundle from which I hoped to load the class dynamically
2- `ImportPackage: *` in the same manner as 1

Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do something that would be better achieved using OSGi Services. Can you describe why you need to do these classloading tricks instead of just using a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neil is right. You should use services for that. In your bundle B (or in separate bundle C) create an interface S that is your service contract. In your bundle A implement that interface and register an OSGi service with it. Then in your class in bundle B add optional greedy service reference to  S. This way

- B does not depend on A (don't need A in compile classpth)
- A depends on B (or C if you decide to extract S into own bundle)
- B can start with or without A
- when A is installed it registers S then B is notified and can call S (to get your object for example)
- when A is uninstalled it unregisters S then B is notified and can cleanup